# HTML Input Type Range

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html

I am developing a simple web-based Function Point calculator.

This is my original webpage. 
http://functionpoint.zxq.net/original/

```
<input type="button"  style="font-size:100%" style="height: 160px; width: 420px"     name="bClearEntry" value="Reset / Clear all form entries" onclick="fResetAll()">
```

I have designed another webpage which is similar to the original
http://functionpoint.zxq.net/

```
<label for="a1">Number of user input</label>
<input id="a1" name="a1" type="range" onchange="showValue(this,'a1Value');" min="0"    max="5" value="3" />
```

I replace radio button with "range" attribute which is a HTML 5 elements.

My problem:  type="range" only allows numerical input (0-5 in this case). Is it possible to allow non-numerical input (Simple, Average, Complex)?

- "range" attribute is not supported in IE and Firefox. Any alternative methods to replace radio button in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a `<select>` dropdown list?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

This seems like what you're looking for: [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps)

Comment: Thank your for the help. However, it's not what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a slider which allows non-numerical input. http://jsbin.com/upeyew This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: well, you can map numbers to the text you like…

Comment: and that is exactly what the solution you linked to does :D